# How to get a CSV file opened in a specified encoding

Tags: c#, csv, encoding

I get an array of bytes encoded in Windows-1255.

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
...
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(result);
```

and save it as a CSV file.

```
var str = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).GetString(bytes);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\folder\\file.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)))
{   
    sw.Write(str);
}
```

when I open the CSV file I see Jibberish:

> çã÷ ááä

solution ?

Comment: Can you post an example of the **Jibrish**?

Comment: Please post the code of the save to CSV. Also post a sample of how you retrieve the existing bytes.

Comment: Is the Windows-1255 encoding a requirement? Would saving the CSV in a more standard encoding solve your issue?

Comment: How are you saving the Code to the CSV file? Also what locale is your machine set to?

Comment: @user2265025 better to edit your question and put it in there so we get the benefit of formatting.

Comment: @Pluc Only Windows-1255 encodes it correctly

Comment: "When I open the CSV" Open with what?

Comment: @Pluc with Microsoft Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  after clarification I see why you are encoding to bytes... however you don't need to decode your bytes... just write your result.

The following code works fine for me whether using UTF8 or Windows-1255.  I can open the resulting CSV in notepad++ or excel.

```
Encoding encodingOfChoice = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] bytes = encodingOfChoice.GetBytes(text);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\folder\\folder.csv", 
        false, encodingOfChoice))
{
    sw.Write(result);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
This issue isn't really writing the correct encoding.  It's getting the program that opens it to read the encoding properly.  I was able to get excel and notepad++ to read the characters properly when I used Unicode encoding but I had to make it tab delimited for excel to open in columns properly.

Comment: why is that a problem ?

Comment: btw, later on i want to send this encoded bytes array as an attachment with MemoryStream(bytes). so no way im giving up encoding

Comment: lol... no problem... that's why I made my comment... "unless there is some other reason"... still you don't have to decode unecessarily...

Comment: kevin .. did u write to TEXT any windows-1255 chars ? did u open the file and everything showed correctly ?

Comment: I tested it with data but if you have specific characters you need it to work for give me some sample text and I can try it.  Also to make it even faster to get answers... post something like that in your question.

Comment: btw, this is hebrew and it says my name :)

Comment: OK this is a different problem.  The problem is that the actual program doesn't know the encoding to use when it opens the file I think.  Give me a minute.

Comment: did u figure it out ?

Comment: Check out my edit.  I had to switch to Unicode and use tab delimited instead of CSV (not sure why it seems like CSV should work).